# cloudfront not download .mp3 file

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a problem that aws cloudfront is not downloading a .mp3 file, which I have in my bucket.
I've already made the folder where the file is public, but even so when I access the page using these .mp3 files I get 403 (forbidden).
If anyone can help me thank you.

PS: All files in my bucket are public.

Comment: do you manage to access your content not via the CloudFront url ? i.e. directly from S3 ?

Comment: First, try to access the mp3 file directly from the Amazon S3 bucket via a URL that does not contain any authentication. If that works, then try using the CloudFront distribution to download **other files** (eg non-mp3) from the same bucket. Let us know how it goes!

Comment: yes if i add or deep link in browser run without major problems